# How do I access a private variable from a method?

Tags: java, private, access-specifier

```
currentColor = getCarColor(this.car.color)
```

Here `color` is private and `getCarColor` is a method, how do I access the variable `color`?

Comment: That breaks encapsulation. Unless you have an extremely good reason, don't. If you do have a good reason, you can use reflection.

Comment: That's the reason we use setters and getters for variables in a class rather than accessing them directly

Comment: If the private variable is inside a class that you own, why not add a getter method to the class?

Comment: There already is a public getter method, getCarColor (as I understand it... ), but it's not doing what I think it should be doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be accessing private variables directly: they are made private for a reason.

The proper way to do it is to add a *public* accessor method for the color to the car:

```
class Car {
    private Color color;
    // Add this method:
    public Color getColor() { return color; }
}
```

Comment: There already is a public getter method, getCarColor (as I understand it... ), but it's not doing what I think it should be doing.

Comment: @user3328737 You are calling it like `this.car.getCarColor()`, right?

Comment: @user3328737 You are welcome. If you no longer need help with this, consider accepting the answer to indicate to other site visitors that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer.

Comment: I think my previous comment because of swear word... : ) I'll mark it as answered as soon as I can figure out how.